# Sort descending and ascending on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table

I am sorting a table and when I click, the order goes to ascending but not descending. I have a boolean value that should toggle true or false but it keeps logging out the initial value. Can someone help me understand why the if statement isn't working? Also when I sort how do I return to the original array?

```
 let sortDirection = false;
    const sortTable = (key) => {
        sortDirection = !sortDirection
        const clonedOptions = [...listOfOptions];
        clonedOptions.sort((a, b) => {
            return sortDirection ? a[key] - b[key] : b[key] - a[key];
        })
        setListOfOptions(clonedOptions);
    }

 <div className="outputs" >
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th onClick={() => sortTable('clock')}>Date </th>
                            <th onClick={() => sortTable('name')}>Stock Name</th>
                            <th onClick={() => sortTable('price')}>Price Of Option</th>
                            <th onClick={() => sortTable('amountOfOptions')}>Number Of Options</th>
                            <th onClick={() => sortTable('totalAmountSpent')}>Total Amount Spent</th>
                            <th onClick={() => sortTable('optionPriceSoldAt')}>Option Sold At</th>
                            <th onClick={() => sortTable('amountOfOptionsSold')}>Amount Of Options Sold</th>
                            <th onClick={() => sortTable('totalProfit')}>Proft</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    {listOfOptions.map((option) => {
                        return (
                            <tbody key={uuidv1()}>
                                <tr>
                                    <td title="delete" onClick={() => deleteOption(option.id)}><span className="delete">x</span></td>
                                    <td>{option.clock}</td>
                                    <td>{option.name.toUpperCase()}</td>
                                    <td>${option.price}</td>
                                    <td>{option.amountOfOptions}</td>
                                    <td>${option.totalAmountSpent.toFixed(2)}</td>
                                    <td>${option.optionPriceSoldAt}</td>
                                    <td>{option.amountOfOptionsSold}</td>
                                    <td style={{ color: option.totalProfit >= 0 ? 'green' : 'red' }}>${option.totalProfit.toFixed(2)}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        )
                    })}
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the boolean into *state*, otherwise, on each render, it'll start out as `false`:

```
const [sortDirection, setSortDirection] = useState(false);
const sortTable = (key) => {
    setSortDirection(!sortDirection);
    const clonedOptions = [...listOfOptions];
    clonedOptions.sort((a, b) => {
        return sortDirection ? b[key] - a[key] : a[key] - b[key];
    })
    setListOfOptions(clonedOptions);
}
```

Comment: That did that trick but why didn't the original way work. Isn't it essentially the same thing.

Comment: They're not the same thing at all - your original way is assigning `false` to a new `sortDirection` variable every render. It never changes, except inside the soon-to-be-GC'd old `sortTable` function. To preserve values over different renders, you need to use state, or a ref, or something like that.

Comment: I'm still new to javascript but shouldn't the if statement take care of the boolean. Sorry for the questions, I'm just trying to understand. Thanks for the quick responses.

Comment: You do not have any `if` statement anywhere in the code? I don't know what you're referring to

Comment: Isn't the return statement an if statement

Comment: I don't see any. Control-F, type `if`, nothing comes up for it in the code